# Using the Key param rather than Id with Pimcore Static Routes

Tags: static, routes, key, pimcore

I looked at the older archived Pimcore forum (topic 2065) which had a really close question and tried the answer I found there but still did not succeed. I could not find any response to my questions here despite all my research.

I have created a website under Pimcore which is using the same static routes methods as the Pimcore demo, which means all articles end up with an id number like _b12. Google does not seem to want to index all these pages. It would apparently be a better idea to use the "key" param (which is unique in my case). I could even add the year and date if necessary.

I have tried many many different scenarios to make sure I fully understand how static routes work.

I have a demo site that I created. The first "pages" show articles the way Pimcore does, the last one is what I would like :

My page seems to successfully load up with the URL I want :

```
http://btfdemo.balsatic.com/blog-entries/article-premier-objet.
```

**In my blog index file:**

```
$detailLink = $this->url([
                    "key" => $article->getKey()
                    ], "blogroutetest", true);
```

**In my Controller (Detail action) :**

```
$article = Object_BlogArticle::getByPath("/blog-entries/" . $this->getParam("key"));
```

**My static route for blogroutetest :**

```
@^/blog-entries/(.*)@  reverse : /blog-entries/%key  variable key
```

Please let me know why I still can't access the article ?

Also, I noted that when I alter the static route in the pimcore admin, it does not modify the file static routes.php in the var/config directory. When I alter the file manually, the static routes are corrected in the admin... Do I have a read/write problem there or is this normal ?

Thanks

Comment: Does your detail action even get called? Try putting a die statement or a breakpoint in it to see if it's called. Do you maybe have some other similar static routes that might match before Pimcore even uses the "blogroutetest" route?

Comment: Thanks Igor. I will try this. I wish I could use a debugger within Pimcore, but I never found a good way to do a step by step like we would in C or Java for instance...  I will have to look deeper into this debugger question. Until then, I have partially solved my problem by creating a link with /_n%id/key which kind of responds to what I wanted to do... but is not optimal....

Comment: Hello Igor. I have tried what you suggest. As we could predict, the detail action is not even called indeed. To be called, the route would have to be recognised and identified... but the problem must come from something else...

Comment: Anything in /website/var/log/debug.log? Can you post a screenshot of the actuall static route config?

Comment: Hello Igor. No nothing interesting. Since then, I gave up trying to use only the key to route my page, I never made it work that way, so I now will use the key plus id. I now tried and succeded to make routing work with nice url getting fully translated according to the language you chose. As I am new to Pimcore, I think I will eventually make it work later with just the key. I am now trying to learn to use multi-sites. Thanks for your help ; I may come back to this later.

Answer (score 0):

> `@^/blog-entries/(.*)@  reverse : /blog-entries/%key  variable key`

Have you set Controller and Action for this static route?